# OS killing the app when it going to background

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, state-restoration

I'm develop application on React native and have an unexpected behavior. When I minimize the app OS kill it, so when I come back to the app it start loads again. I just want to keep using app from the moment I minimezed it.

[image]

The same when I blocking device. Is it something wrong with my app or it's default behavior of OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by errors in "Release" build of the app. So, it's not a normal behavior!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).